# Concept of Giant in Islam?

Tags: source-identification

What I was told that Hazrat Adam (A.S) was very big (90 feet long) and about many other thing ,like the people of Hazrat Nuh(A.S) and Hazrat Luh(A.S)  was also very big.

**Now my question what is proper reference to this saying ? is it true or not? I have search it reference but I could not find it.**

Answer (score -1):

Here is a hadith from bukhari

Narrated Abu Huraira:

The Prophet said, "Allah created Adam, making him 60 cubits tall. When He created him, He said to him, "Go and greet that group of angels, and listen to their reply, for it will be your greeting (salutation) and the greeting (salutations of your offspring." So, Adam said (to the angels), As-Salamu Alaikum (i.e. Peace be upon you). The angels said, "As-salamu Alaika wa Rahmatu-l-lahi" (i.e. Peace and Allah's Mercy be upon you). Thus the angels added to Adam's salutation the expression, 'Wa Rahmatu-l-lahi,' Any person who will enter Paradise will resemble Adam (in appearance and figure). People have been decreasing in stature since Adam's creation.